# How to add uibutton action in a collection view cell?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

[image]

So I have this collection view with cells containing an edit button, located on the upper right corner. How do I wire up an action into it?

I tried adding `cell.editbutton.addTarget` in `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` But it doesn't detect the touchUpInside Event.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84615/retrieving-values-from-uitableviewcell/84655

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**May be needful for you-**

Write this code in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

**Swift 2.X**

```
let editButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, 40,40))
editButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "editButton.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

cell.addSubview(editButton)
```

**Swift 3.X**

```
let editButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:20, width:40,height:40))
editButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "editButton.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

cell.addSubview(editButton)
```

**And perform your action-**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func editButtonTapped() -> Void {
    print("Hello Edit Button")
}
```

Comment: Where do I write the IBAction, should I write it in the CollectionViewCell Class, or the CollectionViewController?

Comment: Works like a breeze

Comment: Great answer! @ChrisMikkelsen Always use logic inside your controllers.

Answer (score 27):

Create the outlet of your UIButton in UICollectionViewCell, write In

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.button.addTarget(self, 
        action: #selector(self.yourFunc(), 
        for: .touchUpInside)
}

func yourFunc(sender : UIButton){
    print(sender.tag)
}
```

Make sure userInteraction is enable for the button as well as for UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: would be better if swift had click listeners like java, all of this in swift looks like crutch

Comment: This is the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

On UICollectionView cell take button (Programmatically or using storyboard). Add action for that button in cell class file and declare delegate in that cell class file and call same delegate in button action method to perform edit action.

Then implement same delegate in ViewController in which you have created collection view

Answer (score 1):

```
protocol CollectionViewCellDelegte {
    func collectionViewCellDelegte(didClickButtonAt index: Int)
}

class ImageCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var index = 0
    var delegte: CollectionViewCellDelegte? = nil

    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let del = self.delegte {
            del.collectionViewCellDelegte(didClickButtonAt: index)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please indent your code right and explain what it does? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem and I tried the solution of putting the button.addTarget method inside the [cellForItemAtIndexPath] of the collectionView controller but it is not working, then I tried to have the following code put inside the init() from the UICollectionViewCell, then it worked fine. Hope this is helpful.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), 
for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

And have the action as following:

```
@objc func buttonPressed(){
    print("buttonPressed")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As I understood, you want to invoke edit button action instead of didSelectItemAt:indexPath.
I solved this by override **canBecomeFocused** (return false), then your edit button action will be involved by tapping on edit button

Comment: Clear your answer - canBecomeFocused for what view?